# ZSH with Powerlevel10k didn't work on terminal startup

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm using Fedora 31 and had installed ZSH (Oh-my-zsh) with PowerLevel10k. When I open gnome-terminal I got ZSH as the default shell, as I expected. But Powerlevel10k is just loaded when I type: `source ~/.zshrc`

This is my zshrc file content:

```
plugins=(git)
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
ZSH_THEME=powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k

# To customize prompt, run `p10k configure` or edit ~/.p10k.zsh.
[[ ! -f ~/.p10k.zsh ]] || source ~/.p10k.zsh
"~/.zshrc" 110L, 4104C
```

Another important thing is that every time I type `source ~/.zshrc`, I got the following error, but everything works fine with Powerlevel10k:

```
[ERROR]: When using instant prompt, Powerlevel10k must be loaded before the first prompt.
```

Comment: So the real problem is, that zsh does not source your `~/.zshrc` when started? Can you verify that this is indeed the case? If yes, this needs to be fixed first.

Comment: I really don't know if this is the problem because ZSH works very well, but when I type "source" command, I got the powerlevel10k working too.

Comment: But then it is trivial to debug, since an interactive zsh is supposed to source .zshrc anyway. Just turn on the trace to see what's going on!

Answer (score 8):

You need to move `ZSH_THEME=powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k` above `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`. `ZSH_THEME` tells Oh My Zsh which theme should be loaded, so it must be set before you source Oh My Zsh.